# jquery wait for ajax method call

Tags: jquery, ajax

getOptionsData does an ajax call to fetch a list of options and updates to a fancybox's select div. Once the getOptionsData's ajax call is over,then a fancybox has to be shown by calling openFancyBox.

I think best place for putting openFancyBox method should be inside "success" function in getoptionsData. But, that function is already being used in many places where this fancyBox is not needed.

How can I simulate this behaviour from inside of showFancyBox() method. Because, current implementation below does not wait for getoptionsData ajax to complete before calling fancyBox..

I tried using "then"  : getoptionsData().then(test.openFancyBox()), but it did not solve.

```
        var test = {

        'getOptionsData': function () {
            var uri = encodeURI(ajaxURL);

            var success = function (data) {
                var optionsList = data.optionsList;
                for (var i = 0; i < optionsList.length; i++) {
                    $("#selectDiv").append("<option value='" + optionsList[i].key + "'>" + optionsList[i].value + "</option>");
                }
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: uri,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                success: success
            });

        },


        'showFancyBox': function () {

          test.getOptionsData(); //Does not wait for Ajax call to be completed
          openFancyBox();

        },

    }
```

Comment: How about passing a callback to `getOptionsData`. The `success` function will then call the callback after it does its default thing.

Comment: y no simply add it at the end of the success line

Comment: Json : {"optionsList":[{"key":"1","value":"A1 "},{"key":"2","value":"A2 }]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [callbacks](https://www.google.com.tr/#q=js+callback).

Here is an example;

```
var test {

        'getOptionsData': function (callback) {
            var uri = encodeURI(ajaxURL);

            var success = function (data) {
                var optionsList = data.optionsList;
                for (var i = 0; i < optionsList.length; i++) {
                    $("#selectDiv").append("<option value='" + optionsList[i].key + "'>" + optionsList[i].value + "</option>");
                }
                callback();
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: uri,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                success: success
            });

        },


        'showFancyBox': function () {

          test.getOptionsData(function() {
            openFancyBox();
          }); 
        },

    }
```

**showFancyBox** will be called after **getOptionData** finished

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/):

```
$.when(test.getOptionsData()).done(openFancyBox);
```

Answer (score 1):

From jQuery version 1.5

Try:

```
var test = {

        'getOptionsData': function () {
            var uri = encodeURI(ajaxURL);

            var success = function (data) {
                var optionsList = data.optionsList;
                for (var i = 0; i < optionsList.length; i++) {
                    $("#selectDiv").append("<option value='" + optionsList[i].key + "'>" + optionsList[i].value + "</option>");
                }
            }

            return $.ajax({ //return the promise
                url: uri,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                success: success
            });
        },

        'showFancyBox': function () {

          test.getOptionsData().done(function(){ //use done instead of then if the version is below 1.8
                test.openFancyBox();
          }); 
        },
    }
```